# Is there any event generated when tag is added to an existing S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'd like to have an AWS lambda triggered when a tag is added to an existing object in S3 bucket (in the same way as we can do it for object create and remove). Any way to do that?

Comment: No, only supported event types are http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types

Comment: Thanks, I know the list of events per objects, I though it might be something separate for tags.

Comment: tags will be for "objects" right? none of the event types are related to "tagging", so not supported.

Answer (score 3):

If you setup Cloudtail you could have a Lambda function monitor the logs and notify you on the tagging event PutBucketTagging

Example Lambda function
https://github.com/retailnext/aws-lambda-cloudtrail-alert

Cloudtail Documentation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html

Comment: Interesting stuff, but the declared latency of up to 15 minutes makes it practically unusable.

Answer (score 3):

Object tagging events are now supported:

```
s3:ObjectTagging:*
s3:ObjectTagging:Put
s3:ObjectTagging:Delete
```

Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html

Answer (score 2):

No. There are no events generated when a tag is added to an object.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html) there is `s3:ObjectTagging:*` event type, which can be used as Lambda trigger.