# Triggering an AWS lambda when an S3 object's tags are created, deleted or changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that tracks an S3 bucket's objects and their tags, and want to keep the table consistent with the objects' state. This means updating the table when object tags are added, removed, or deleted.

Currently I am trying to achieve the above by running a Lambda that writes to the table when the above events occur. I'm having trouble finding tag-related triggers for my use case.

Here are some potential solutions that I've researched:

- S3 PUT trigger, for detecting tag creation: However, it seems like this trigger is only activated for object creation, and not for [PutObjectTagging PUT requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObjectTagging.html).

[image]

- [Creating a CloudWatch rule for detecting tag changes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/monitor-tag-changes-on-aws-resources-with-serverless-workflows-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/): The problem with this one is that the tag support doesn't seem to include anything beyond the service level, such as tag changes to S3 objects. Also, tag creation and deletion are left out by this solution.

Comment: Don't think that such trigger is suported as of now by AWS. But here is a workaround using cloudtrail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034860/is-there-any-event-generated-when-tag-is-added-to-an-existing-s3-object

Comment: "tag support doesn't seem to include anything beyond the service level", if you still remember, what do you mean by the "service level"? Isn't S3 also a service/resource? Im not aware of any differences between those two terms.